# How to extract second word of the string via windows batch

Tags: batch

I would like to request an assist for this case. I want to get the second word of title so that I could set it as target file.

```
set title=THE PROGRAM TITLE HERE
```

Comment: How to extract LAST word of the string?

Answer (score 5):

```
set title=one two three four five
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ("%title%") do set word2=%%i
echo %word2%
```

This basically grabs the second token (word) from the string. Change the number behind `tokens=` into another to get another word. You can also use `tokens=2,4` to get the 2nd and 4th word. Additional tokens can be retrieved from `%%j`, `%%k` etc.

See `for /?` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a local subroutine, passing the title unquoted.  In the subroutine, that would give you a list of parameters, e.g., `%1` for "THE", `%2` for "PROGRAM".

Something like

```
call :second
echo The second word is %second_word%
```

and later:

```
:second
   set second_word=%2
   goto :eof
```