# Windows batch file to move files to subfolders based on first word in file name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I am bit of a batch file noob, so I'd really appreciate your help. I have a ton of files stored in a single directory which I wish to sort into subfolders based on the first word in their filenames. So, I have files like these:

```
C:\Folder\Wedding2018 img20929.jpg 
C:\Folder\Wedding2018 entrance.mov
C:\Folder\Wedding2018 registry of guests.pdf

C:\Folder\HorseRiding2017 spirit1.jpg
C:\Folder\HorseRiding2017 guests.txt 
C:\Folder\HorseRiding2017 certificate.pdf
C:\Folder\HorseRiding2017 jumping.mov
```

And I wish to move all files to subfolders based on the first word, ending up like this:

```
C:\Folder\Wedding2018\img20929.jpg
C:\Folder\Wedding2018\entrance.mov
C:\Folder\Wedding2018\registry of guests.pdf

C:\Folder\HorseRiding2017\spirit1.jpg
C:\Folder\HorseRiding2017\guests.txt
C:\Folder\HorseRiding2017\certificate.pdf
C:\Folder\HorseRiding2017\jumping.mov
```

I've found a couple of scripts that *almost* do what I need, but I don't have the chops to bring it home:

["Need a script to create folders based on file names, and auto move files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441317/need-a-script-to-create-folders-based-on-file-names-and-auto-move-files)

["How to extract second word of the string via windows batch"](https://superuser.com/questions/918167/how-to-extract-second-word-of-the-string-via-windows-batch)

I just can't work out how to integrate the script to grab the first word and make a directory to which the files will be moved.

**Can you help me get this across the line?**

Answer (score 4):

- Use one for to iterate folder content `%%A` with a pattern containing at
  least one space.
- Another `for /f`is needed to split the name `%%A` into two parts, one before
  the first space `tokens=1` = `%%B` and the rest `tokens *` = `%%C`.
- If a folder with the name of `%%B` doesn't exist create it
- Move the original file `%%A` to the subfolder `%%B` with the name `%%C`

---

```
:: Q:\2018\06\11\SU_1330475.cmd
@Echo off
PushD C:\folder
for %%A in ("* *.*") do for /f "tokens=1*" %%B in ("%%A") do (
     If not exist "%%B" MD "%%B"
     Move "%%A" "%%B\%%C"
)
PopD
```

---

```
> tree /f
C:.
│   SU_1330475.cmd
│
└───folder
    ├───HorseRiding2017
    │       certificate.pdf
    │       guests.txt
    │       jumping.mov
    │       spirit1.jpg
    │
    └───Wedding2018
            entrance.mov
            img20929.jpg
            registry of guests.pdf
```

Comment: this worked like an absolute charm - thank you. In testing with a large volume of files, the only hiccup I noticed was that for files with a double space after the first word, it failed to handle them at all - easily fixed

Comment: If you find my answer useful, consider chack marking as answer and/or [vote up](https://superuser.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score -1):

Does it have to be a batch file?

I would open the main folder where all files and subfolders are located, next you go to the search field in that window and type wedding* for example. You select all files by preesing CTRL + A, then you press CTRL + X to cut.

You create a new folder called Wedding2018 and press CTRL + V (paste). So you do for each folder you want.